Is it possible to write in more than one Database using Mongock?
Is it possible to write in more than one database in Mongock?
I am trying to write in 2 different databases using Mongock.
@ChangeSet(order = "005", id = "changeWithMongockTemplate1", author = "mongock")
public void changeWithMongockTemplate(MongockTemplate mongockTemplate1) {
  mongockTemplate1.save("save to database1");
}

@ChangeSet(order = "006", id = "changeWithMongockTemplate2", author = "mongock")
public void changeWithMongockTemplate(MongockTemplate mongockTemplate2) {
  mongockTemplate2.save("save to database2");
}

Is it possible to write in 2 different database?

Well, this is a tricky question.
First at all, technically you can write to any number of databases you want, you just need to inject the right MongoTemplate. You can probably do this y using named beans.
However, you probably want to run your changes in the same transaction that the Mongock writes the audit log(write to the changelogs collection), in all-or-nothing fashion.
As you can imagine, if you write your change to two independent databases and write the change log to one of them, you are in a risk of get into a race condition. So I suggest to split that into two completely Mongock runners, each one pointing to the database you want to write to.
Sad that, I don't really know your case, but this is an approach I wouldn't recommend in general
